# Basic Magnolia project wont start

Tags: maven, content-management-system, magnolia

I cannot run the most simple of Magnolia projects.

I followed these basic instructions as specified from the official site (except with Eclipse):
http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects

I tried with  magnolia-version  5.2    and repeated with 5.2.1-SNAPSHOT

It SUCCESSFULLY built.

But when I run on Tomcat I get this:

2013-12-19 11:07:51,368 ERROR info.magnolia.init.MagnoliaServletContextListener : Oops, Magnolia could not be started
info.magnolia.module.model.reader.ModuleDependencyException: The following exceptions were found while checking Magnolia modules dependencies (i.e. those in META-INF/magnolia/my-module.xml):
Module Magnolia DMS Module (version 1.5.2) is dependent on fckEditor version 4.4/*, which was not found.
Module Magnolia DAM Module (version 1.2.0) is dependent on dms version 1.6/*, but Magnolia DMS Module (version 1.5.2) is currently installed.

```
at info.magnolia.module.model.reader.DependencyCheckerImpl.checkDependencies(DependencyCheckerImpl.java:71)
```

Answer (score 2):

It built because you don't have compile time dependency problem. However you have module dependency problem.

> Module Magnolia DMS Module (version 1.5.2) is dependent on fckEditor version 4.4/, which was not found. Module Magnolia DAM Module (version 1.2.0) is dependent on dms version 1.6/, but Magnolia DMS Module (version 1.5.2) is currently installed.

There is no fckEditor module in Magnolia 5, so you can't have such module installed and that's why DMS version you are trying to install is complaining, because that DMS version depends on fckEditor module.
Looking at http://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MGNLDMS#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversions-panel the DMS version you are trying to install is quite old one - from 2011 … why don't you try to change your project configuration to depend on latest - 1.6.10 version of DMS instead? BTW Magnolia 5 doesn't use DMS it was replaced by DAM so you should not need to depend on DMS at all. Where did you get that dependency from?  (mvm dependency:tree might help to figure it out if it's not directly declared in your webapp pom).

Also you might ask at http://forum.magnolia-cms.com … there's pbly more Magnolia users there than here.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and added in a dependency on DMS as a result of following this tutorial: http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects.  In Magnolia 5 you don't seem to need the DMS module, so just don't add that in and you should be fine.